# Query not updating data in Oozie editor

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, oozie-workflow

I am using Oozie editor (HUE) where I made a workflow that has HiveServer2 script, that runs a SQL query for creating a table in Hive DB.

[image: Oozie Editor]

Query is:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbname.table1 (key INT, value STRING);
```

It runs successfully but I can't see any table name **table1** inside **dbname** database.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to do is, just put a new line in the end of query.
Some how I found this while experimenting in query.
If your .sql contains more than 1 query then after first query put a new line then start another query and one more thing to remind that your query itself should not contain any new line (\n); add blank new line to your last query.
That's it.